# How to pass an argument into a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Is it possible to pass an argument from a shell script and pass it to a file.
This is what I am essentially trying to achieve:

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash -

input=$1
DIR=/home/user/

File=$DIR/test.txt

`cat $File` < $input
```

this is the test.txt:

```
select * from abc where date=$input;
```

I am pretty new to this stuff. please help if there's a correct approach to it.

Comment: since you are new to Shell, I would recommend reading at least https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/BourneShellScripting.pdf

Comment: Yes it is possible. Read documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). For your case, you could prefer learning then using [Python](http://python.org/) or [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will go through!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use cat but rather echo for this particular scenario.

```
echo "select * from abc where date='$input'" > test.txt
```

The double quotes will redirect and WRITE the echo along with the sentence expanded input variable to the text.txt variable.

If you want to append as opposed to write, use:

```
echo "select * from abc where date='$input'" >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can it be the other way around? like instead of passing the whole query just $input value into the text file? is it possible? thanks for your time.

Comment: If the file already contains the select statement, then you would have to edit the file using something like sed.

Comment: Thank you this worked! sed "s/x/$input/g" $File.txt